# HttpRedirects in Web.Config not redirecting as desired

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, redirect

I'm running IIS10 in my dev server but only IIS8.5 on my production server. I'm just pointing out - nothing to do with the issue I have.

I'm using C#/web forms with url routing and am looking to move some httpredirects into my web.config file.

Having looked at the documentation, I have configured it like this:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" exactDestination="true">
  <add wildcard="/red-widget2" destination="/widgets/red-widget" />
</httpRedirect>
```

Given that I've used exact destination, I expected just that, but it's not what I'm currently getting.

If I enter a url like this:

> https://example.com/red-widget2

I expect a destination like this:

> https://example.com/widgets/red-widget

But I actually get this:

> https://example.com/widgets/red-widget/red-widget2

I've tried all the attributes to no avail, so how do I correctly configure this redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer for anyone else that falls into this trap.

The code I posted above works - it's just that IIS/Chrome doesn't want me to know.

I exited IIS, shut down the project, restarted VS, but still was left with the same issue.

However, when I cleared my browser cache and tried again, I got the answer I needed. What happened was, while I was testing, either IIS or the browser decided they were gonna keep hold of the wrong redirects and keep presenting them back to me, no matter what I changed.

So there it is - if you don't get it right first time, clear your browser cache.

Comment: It is very likely that you tested with different settings in the iteration and finally figured out the right ones. That means old settings can be remembered by the browser you use, because 301 redirection would be cached. Yes, clearing the browser cache would then fix the issue.